# Current waveform distortion on transformer with a load resistor on secondary winding

Tags: transformer, saturation

Why does the current from a transformer with a load resistor quickly rise and fall (yellow wave-form)?
(Transformer without a load resistor (white, primary)).

[image: Transformer with load resistor]

Comment: Can you add the input waveform to compare? Without knowing what goes in we can only guess. Both look quite ugly, and not the clean sinewave I would expect. Transformers do tend to give some distortion because of the saturation of the core and such.

Comment: Because of that load resistor and leakage inductance are forming a filter and chopping off some high frequency components maybe?

Comment: Which current primary or secondary? I assume primary, but you also omitted an important detail - voltage trace. This because you will also find a phase shift between them.

Answer (score 1):

The white waveform is the magnetizing current for the transformer. With an ideal unloaded transformer (a pure inductance), this would be a sine wave that is shifted by 90° to the right (lagging) from the primary voltage. However, your actual transformer is operating close to saturation, so you start to see those odd narrow peaks at the top and bottom as the effective inductance drops.

The yellow waveform can be understood as the superposition (sum) of the white waveform plus a second sine wave that is in-phase (0° shift) with the line voltage. This second wave represents the additional current being drawn by the (resistive) load.